# EAGLE Schematic Design Best Practices

Tags: schematics, eaglecad, best-practice

I am currently learning how to use EAGLE. My end-goal is to have a simple PCB printed in China for a project that I am working on.
Since I don't have experience in designing schematics, what would be some design considerations that are considered "best practice" that I did not follow in my schematic?

In my design, the 22-04-1021 components are molex connectors, which I intend to solder onto the PCB to connect 4 force sensitive resistors (FSR1-4), a spring-applied brake (BRK), a signal wire and GND going to a different device (SIGNAL), and the 24V power for the brake. This leads me to two questions:

1. Is it correct to have the connectors in the schematic like this, considering that once I create the layout, that's where I would need the component's dimensions to create holes for soldering?
2. How should I manage the 24V connection and the associated GND? As I have an opto-coupler separating the microprocessor from the different voltage circuit, I cannot use the same GND symbol to connect the 24V grounds together. So I just connected the directly as there aren't too many of them.
   To keep track of which of the two wires is supposed to be GND and 24V, I created a label for them, but that doesn't feel quite right.

Lastly, I intend to power the microprocessor using a seperate 5V power source rather than using the power from the USB. I hope that I chose the correct symbols in my schematic.

[image: Schematic]

Comment: I'm afraid with every language around the world, your right to left and upside down grounds is totally inconsistent with the rules of making schematics universally equally easy to read in any language including Japan, China and Iran.   Go read some IPC design specs or major corporation service manuals and get some experience reading schematics before you try to create your own bad rules in graphic design of schematics.   V+=up, Gnd = down including NPN emitters, inputs on left , outputs on right

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/28251/rules-and-guidelines-for-drawing-good-schematics/28255#28255 is a decent intro on this site :)